# Index optimization for query on timestamps

Tags: mysql, indexing, timestamp

```
SELECT
node_session_seq,
call_start,
YEAR(call_start) AS year,
quarter(call_start) as qtr,
ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(call_start, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),1) AS month,
CAST(call_start AS DATE) AS date,
CASE WHEN MAX(queue_time) <= sla AND MAX(cont_disp) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS presented,
CASE WHEN MAX(cont_disp) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS handled,
CASE WHEN MAX(queue_time) <= sla AND MAX(cont_disp = 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS met_sla,
CASE WHEN MAX(queue_time) > sla AND MAX(cont_disp = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS abandoned
FROM
emsupport.t_cisco_csq_ad csq_ad where call_start > '2013-03-30 00:00:00'
GROUP BY node_session_seq
```

Above is a query that I'm using to build a datamart for call reporting.  My question surrounds performance - current there are 5 indexes on the table:

- Primary Key / INT(11) Auto-increment
- call_start / DATETIME
- cont_disp / VARCHAR(45)  - valid values are 1,2,3,4,99
- csq_name / VARCHAR(90) / UNRELATED
- app_name / VARCHAR(90) / UNRELATED

Should I just add indexes to queue_time and SLA?  SLA would be either 45, 60, 90, 120, 200 or 300 in timestamp format, same as the queue time.  Queue time will have quite a few commonalities; a majority of our call volume is answered in < 60 seconds.  Presently I am seeing performance of about 1000 rows in 23-25 seconds.  That is with a partial dataset of about 515k rows, with total being about 750k.

Will indexes do the trick?  Or is there something else I should be doing?  I'm not a DBA, just a guy that knows enough SQL to get more work on his plate.

Thanks for the help - oh and PS - insertion performance is not an issue.  Its completed off hours by a script on a daily basis only inserting new data.

Jim

//Edited/Adding Create Statement for Table

```
CREATE TABLE `t_cisco_csq_ad` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `node_session_seq` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `call_start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `call_end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `cont_disp` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `origin_dn` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `dest_dn` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `called_number` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_name` varchar(90) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `csq_name` varchar(90) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `queue_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `agent_name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ring_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `talk_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `work_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `isrna` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `agent_resourceid` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sla` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `i_call_start` (`call_start`),
  KEY `i_csq_name` (`csq_name`),
  KEY `i_app_name` (`app_name`),
  KEY `i_cont_disp` (`cont_disp`)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=676886 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, your description of `SLA` and queue time is imprecise.

Comment: @rick-james the SLA is simply the contractually agreed service time for our clients.  Basically the queue_time is how long it took to answer each call, the sla is the time its compared against.
Would it make more sense to do the comparison in a trigger when new rows are inserted, do the comparison and just store it as a column as true/false?  Would that provide faster summary results?

Answer (score 0):

The only useful index is `INDEX(call_start)`.

It smells like `cont_disp` should be `TINYINT UNSIGNED`.  Or maybe `ENUM(...)`